# Font rendering issues in mobile app

Tags: bug, android-app, mobile-app, fonts

While browsing the codegolf [hot question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/177765) today, I noticed that the font rendering had some issues.

Check the screenshots below:

### (in app)

> [image: app]

### (in browser)

> [image: browser]

Comment: No repro on iOS app on my phone.

Comment: No repro on SE app 1.0.95, Nexus 5, LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1). Could you provide relevant device & OS info?

Comment: @andmyself SE beta 1.0.95. Samsung galaxy running Android 5.1.1

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm running SE Android App 1.0.95 on my Motorola G5+, Android 8.1.0.